# How do you typecast void pointers?

Tags: c, casting, type-conversion

I'm currently working on a problem where I have to make a void pointer into a signed char, short, long, long long.
(These seem simple I can just created a tmp, and cast the void.)

What confuses me is:
converting the void pointer into:
signed decimal, unsigned octal, unsigned decimal, unsigned hexadecimal, %f conversion where, "double arg is rounded and covered to decimal notation.

With the majority of these conversions I would just use atoi with a base correct?

I'll be using variadic arguments, and will know what the value is actually, but my plan is to typecast everything as a void pointer, and then convert them depending on the format. The conversions are what I'm unclear about. For clarity: I'm casting the va_arg as a void pointer, and storing it in a struct. Then depending on the format I will be converting each void pointer to the correct data type. I'm simply trying to figure out how to do each conversion to the data types listed above

Thank you for any and all help.

```
void    ft_conversion_length_di(t_main *node)
{
    if (node->length == 'H')
        node->arg = (signed char)node->arg;
    if (node->length == 'h')
        node->arg = (short)node->arg;
    if (node->length == 'l')
        node->arg = (long)node->arg;
    if (node->length == 'E')
        node->arg = (long long)node->arg;
}
```

Comment: *void pointer into a signed char....* - you mean to a *pointer* to these? Or to an actual numeric type? And your question is a mixture of subjects. Give us a single example code and ask a specific question.

Comment: Please show an example of what you're attempting to do.

Comment: What do you mean by "converting the void pointer into: signed decimal, unsigned octal, unsigned decimal, unsigned hexadecimal ..."? Those aren't C types.

Comment: A description is not enough, as those can be vauge.  Sample code with an attempt at solving the problem along with input and expected output will give us a better idea of what exactly you want to do.

Comment: You can only typecast *if and only if* the value is actually what you attest it to be. If you have `void*` but it's actually a `double` in memory then typecasting it to `int` will result in miserable failure, the binary representations are different. `atoi` is *only* for converting ASCII representations. If you don't know what your `void*` points to, figure it out.

Comment: I'll be using variadic arguments, and will know what the value is actually, but my plan is to typecast everything as a void pointer, and then convert them depending on the format. 

The conversions are what I'm unclear about.
For clarity:
I'm casting the va_arg as a void pointer, and storing it in a struct.
Then depending on the format I will be converting each void pointer to the correct data type.
I'm simply trying to figure out how to do each conversion to the data types listed above.

Answer (score 1):

If you're reading values from a variadic function where you know the type, `void *` is not what you want.  You can convert from a `void *` to another pointer type, but not to a "value" type.

What you want instead is a union which can hold any of the types you expect, along with a struct containing that union and a type indicator.

For example

```
enum value_type {
    VAL_CHAR,
    VAL_SHORT,
    VAL_LONG,
    VAL_LONGLONG,
    VAL_FLOAT,
    VAL_DOUBLE
};

union val {
   char c;
   short s;
   long l;
   long long ll;
   float f;
   double d;
};

struct value {
    enum value_type type;
    union val v;
};


void myfunc(const char *format, ...)
{
    va_list ap;

    va_start(ap, format);
    while (/* has more values */) {
        struct value s;
        if (/* is char */) {
            s.type = VAL_CHAR;
            s.v.c = va_arg(ap, char);
        } else if (/* is short */) {
            s.type = VAL_SHORT;
            s.v.s = va_arg(ap, short);
        } else if (/* is long */) {
            s.type = VAL_LONG;
            s.v.l = va_arg(ap, long);
        } else if (/* is long long */) {
            s.type = VAL_LONGLONG;
            s.v.ll = va_arg(ap, long long);
        } else if (/* is float */) {
            s.type = VAL_FLOAT;
            s.v.l = va_arg(ap, float);
        } else if (/* is double */) {
            s.type = VAL_DOUBLE;
            s.v.l = va_arg(ap, double);
        }
        /* do something with s */
    }
    va_end(ap);
}
```

Comment: So, for my understanding. 
The void pointer is just acting like a pointer, and not holding any true value when simply typecasted.

Is this why you don't have to malloc space for void pointers, because they are just pointing to an address? 
 
I'm not saying this is a rational way of doing it, but if the void pointer, pointed to the correct data type the output still would not be a "value" type correct?

So, this is why unions would be a better way to go? 
Thank you for clearing stuff up!

Comment: @AlanBarrettII The problem is that `va_arg` returns the given value, not a pointer to it, so you can't just point a `void *` to the return value.  It doesn't make sense to do something like `int x=4; void *p = x;`